# What is more portable: pseudo class ":hover" or jQuery's "hover()"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, custom-controls

What is more portable to implement custom imaged button: to make CSS rules with pseudo classes hover, focus and active or to process events with jQuery's methods like hover(), addStyle(), removeStyle() etc?

Comment: Portable between what? Define the browsers you would like to support.

Comment: I mean average browsers nowadays.

Comment: please define *average browsers nowadays*. If you are not able to define your requirements it is unlikely you will get correct answers. Programming is an **exact** science. I like to say that a poorly defined problem usually leads to poor solutions.

Comment: This definition is part of my question. If I knew the list of browsers, I would check capabilities myself. I.e. I need no help in reading, I need help in estimating.

Answer (score 3):

Always give first preference to `CSS` then `Jquery` or `JS`. There are several reason:

1) we didn't need add extra `Script` tag for `Jquery`. Which save our page `loading time`.

2) `Css` even run when `JS` is `Disable`.